# Updating columns from second table in Oracle master table via procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure where I want to update my master table columns from relevant table.

So below is my SP

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPD_RRSOC_MST_COLUMNS AS 
BEGIN

MERGE
INTO    TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO trg
USING   (
        SELECT  t1.SLP_STATE_HEAD, T2.STATE_HEAD_NAME
        FROM    TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO t1
        JOIN    TBL_STATE_HEAD_INFO t2
        ON      TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO.SLP_STATE_HEAD = TBL_STATE_HEAD_INFO.STATE_HEAD_NAME
       -- WHERE   TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO.UPDATETYPE='blah'
        ) src
ON      (trg.RRSOC_ID = t2.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO.SLP_STATE_HEAD = STATE_HEAD_NAME;

  NULL;
END UPD_RRSOC_MST_COLUMNS;
```

but I am getting error as

> Error(10,55): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "TBL_STATE_HEAD_INFO"."STATE_HEAD_NAME": invalid identifier

How can I create the procedure?

### Update

```html
MERGE INTO TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO trg
USING   (
  SELECT  t1.SLP_STATE_HEAD,
          T2.STATE_HEAD_NAME,
          t2.id,
          t2.STATE_MOB_NUM
  FROM    TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO t1
  JOIN    TBL_STATE_HEAD_INFO t2
          ON t1.SLP_STATE_HEAD = t2.STATE_HEAD_NAME
) src
ON (trg.RRSOC_ID = src.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET SLP_STATE_HEAD = src.STATE_HEAD_NAME,
       SLP_STATE_HEAD_NO = src.STATE_MOB_NUM;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the aliases in the join condition rather than the full table names:

```sql
SELECT  t1.SLP_STATE_HEAD, T2.STATE_HEAD_NAME
FROM    TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO t1
JOIN    TBL_STATE_HEAD_INFO t2
        ON t1.SLP_STATE_HEAD = t2.STATE_HEAD_NAME
```

Then:

```sql
MERGE
INTO    TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO trg
USING   (...) src
ON (trg.RRSOC_ID = t2.ID)
```

Will fail as you do not have an alias in the `MERGE` scope called `t2` you have the aliases `trg` and `src` and `src` does not have an `id` column as it is not one of the columns you are `SELECT`ing.

Then:

```sql
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET SLP_STATE_HEAD = src.STATE_HEAD_NAME;
```

You do not need an alias for the table being updated (it can only be `trg`) but you probably want an alias on the column you are updating from.

Which would give you something like:

```sql
MERGE INTO TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO trg
USING   (
  SELECT  t1.SLP_STATE_HEAD,
          T2.STATE_HEAD_NAME,
          t2.id
  FROM    TBL_RRSOC_STORE_INFO t1
  JOIN    TBL_STATE_HEAD_INFO t2
          ON t1.SLP_STATE_HEAD = t2.STATE_HEAD_NAME
) src
ON (trg.RRSOC_ID = src.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET SLP_STATE_HEAD = src.STATE_HEAD_NAME;
```

Comment: ohh.. what if I want to update more columns in exisitng procedure.. `SLP_STATE_HEAD_NO` is my t1 column. +1 for explaining logically

Comment: @hud Just use `WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET col1 = src.value1, col2 = src.value2` etc. (and make sure the values are included in the `SELECT` statement that defines `src`).

Comment: just see my updated question, if its ok like this for multiple columns to update

Comment: @hud Try it and see [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=048a3f4e3929b2638f602758f5dc4c75). The queries are syntactically valid and run without error; however, whether they do what you want or not is only something you can answer.